# ThreeJS motion - move in a circle over fixed time period

Tags: javascript, time, three.js, trigonometry

I'm attempting to get an object to move along a circular path in a fixed time period.

The application of this is a 'smooth motion' clock.

So, instead of moving the position to a fixed co-ordinate everytime `.getSeconds()` updates, I want to use a combination of `( .getSeconds() + ( .getMilliseconds()/1000 )` in order to accurately represent the motion of the second hand at all times.

For doing circular motion in the past I have used the following pair of functions:

```
    var OrbitCalculationX = function(velocityPartial, orbitalRadius) {
        return (Math.sin(Date.now() / 16000 * velocityPartial) * orbitalRadius);
    };
    var OrbitCalculationZ = function(velocityPartial, orbitalRadius) {
        return (Math.cos(Date.now() / 16000 * velocityPartial) * orbitalRadius);
    };`
```

The `16000` in that calculation controlled the orbital time. However, this is not accurate. Is there a way to control a `x-axis sin vs z-axis cos` equation set that has accurate time constraints?

If not, is there a way to set an animation path to complete in an exact time period in THREEjs?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Three.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope that I understood you correctly here...

Take one minute which has 60 secs and 60,000 msecs. So, the first step we want is to have numbers in that range.

```
var millisInMinute = Date.now() % 60000;
```

next thing we want is to normalize the value, so that it goes from 0 to 1:

```
var millisInMinuteNormalized = millisInMinute / 60000;
```

Now, to make a whole circular movement with sin and cos where we know that our variable will be between 0 and 1, we need to multiply it by 2*PI [see plot here](https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=EtfSVeCcGoOV8Qfj067IDA&gws_rd=cr#q=plot+sin+(x*2*PI)+from+0+to+1.2)

The rest with the radius is like you did it, resulting in

```
var orbitCalculation = function(radius) {
    return {x: (Math.sin((Date.now()%60000)/60000 * Math.PI * 2) * radius),
            z: (Math.cos((Date.now()%60000)/60000 * Math.PI * 2) * radius)};
}
```

The actual seconds are now displayed correctly, you can compare it with your system time. Here is a [working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jk9ybv8m/)